# SMTP relay or proxy to send mails to a server with port 25 blocked

Tags: linux, email, proxy, smtp

I have a server A on a dynmaic DNS, the IP address changes, and port 25 is blocked. It is running sendmail as the MTX server.

Also, I have a server B that has 25 open, but storage limited.

I wonder if I can run SMTP proxy on server B and forward/transfer all the emails to the server A on a different port other than 25? How would I configure that?  What software should I look into on linux/freebsd system?

thank you
Honest Gold

Comment: Which MTA/SMTP and IMAP servers do you prefer to use?